# How I can test smart contract which has logic based on chainId

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, testing, unittesting

Dear blockchain developers, I have a ERC20 with restriction of minting only on Polygon chain:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.23;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract MyPolygonToken is ERC20 {
    uint256 public constant MINT_CHAIN_ID = 137;
    error ZeroAddress();

    constructor(
        string memory _name,
        string memory _symbol,
    ) ERC20(_name, _symbol) {
        if (getChainId() == MINT_CHAIN_ID) {
          _mint(msg.sender, 1_000_000 ether);
        }
    }

    function getChainId() public view returns (uint256) {
        uint256 chainId;
        assembly {
            chainId := chainid()
        }
        return chainId;
    }
}
```

I want to create unit test to test the correct execution, but have problem. I tried to create second local network with id "137" by fork Polygon network, but I can't get the signers of the chain.
Do you have any idea how I can easily do it, or maybe some extension for hardhat which can help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You do not hardcode `MINT_CHAIN_ID` but pass it as a constructor parameter.

Comment: Thanks for response, but it doesn't work for me, because I must be sure that the token will mint only on one chain. If we pass the chainID value in constructor arguments, then we can pass any chainId and the token will be minted on any chain. Or do you mean to create mock token for tests? Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: `f we pass the chainID value in constructor arguments, then we can pass any chainId and the token will be minted on any chain.` You do not understand correctly. If the value is only settable in the constructor, there is no way to change the value after the deployment, making it not different for your use case.

Comment: `If the value is only settable in the constructor, there is no way to change the value after the deployment` yes, you are correct, but I need to check the mint on deployment. I need to restrict initial minting. As you can see I use function `_mint` in constructor

Comment: `As you can see I use function _mint in constructor` does make any sense. When you deploy the contract, and it runs the constructor, you know the chain it is deploying. There is no sense in this check. You cannot deploy a contract and it suddenly runs the constructor on some other chain.

Comment: `When you deploy the contract, and it runs the constructor, you know the chain it is deploying` yes, you correct, but actually I want to create [LayerZero OFT token](https://layerzero.gitbook.io/docs/evm-guides/contract-standards/oft-overview), and the token is deployed on several chains.

Comment: This sounds like  https://xyproblem.info/ - I suggest you open a new question where you explain what you are doing and why, instead of trying to jump to an attempted solution, which does not make sense